# Proving with definition if $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}-a_n=-\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> Prove by definition that: Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that, if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\infty$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}-a_n=-\infty$.

From the defintion, if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\infty$ then: $\forall M\in \mathbb R: M>0:\exists N\in \mathbb R : \forall n>N: a_n>M$.

Multiply both sides $(*)$ of $a_n>M$ by $-1$ and get:  $-a_n<-M$, define $M_2=-M$ and we have: $$\forall M_2\in \mathbb R: M_2<0:\exists N\in \mathbb R : \forall n>N: -a_n<M_2$$

Which is exactly the defintion for $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}-a_n=-\infty$.

I feel like doing $(*)$ is wrong though, is it?

Comment: No, everything is ok.

Comment: Well, you don't need to specify for $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}$ definition that $M>0$. This is perfectly right for indifferently $M<0$ or $M>0$. But your proof is right.

Comment: @servabat oh I saw that in the definition for $+\infty$ they always define $M>0$ and vice versa for $-\infty$.

Comment: Well, there's no reason for that : if $\forall M > 0, \exists N$ then you also have $\forall M \leq 0, \exists N$, just take the $N$ for 1 for example. I think it's "cleaner" just saying $\forall M \in \mathbb{R}$ (but of course, that's just my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine, and your proof is correct! Good job!

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*